# Parse website with Rvest

Tags: r, xml, rvest

```
library(rvest); library(XML); library(magrittr)
#> Loading required package: xml2
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'XML'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:rvest':
#> 
#>     xml

url <- 'http://www.screener.in/company/526965'

basic <- read_html(url)

basic %>% html_nodes('#balancesheet div')
#> {xml_nodeset (0)}

readHTMLTable(url)
#> named list()
```

If you go to the url link, there are certain tables. I am looking to bring in the balance sheet table in R. As can be seen in the code, the `readHTMLTable()` and `html_nodes()` both returns blank and not the table.

Comment: That's b/c all the tables/charts are populated with data from XHR calls. Said XHR calls are also _forbidden_ to be accessed by the site [`robots.txt`](http://www.screener.in/robots.txt) file. Continuing with this endeavour is unethical and may incur civil or criminal penalties for you an those who aid you. I suggest contacting the site and getting written permission to access their hidden API and then use their hidden API.

Comment: Thank you very much for the information. I will skip scraping then!